# I am struggling with creating object this method

Tags: methods, this

This method is not working

```
    /**
    * Outputs all details of all customers to the terminal window.
    */
   public void getAllBorrowers()
   {
       int index = 0;
            while(index < borrowers.size()) 
        {
            borrowers.get(index);
            index++;
        }

        System.out.println("Number of borrowers: " + getNumberOfBorrowers());
    }
```

Comment: "is not working" is not a decent error description.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure what are you trying to do here.

But from the function it looks like you are getting borrower from 
borrowers.get(index);

But not getting the value and printing it.

Can you please let know what exactly you are expecting here?